# What sites are available for hosting Choose Your Own Adventure stories?

Tags: fantasy, planning, resources, branching-narrative, interactive-fiction

I'm working on a story that is like a Choose Your Own Adventure, but different. Instead of being "you" and deciding what to do next, the reader must choose which characters participate at what time. By choosing the characters, you then get to follow a story path involving people most suited to your interests.

The roadblocks I'm encountering are few, but worrisome. The site I'm currently hosting on doesn't have very many members, and a bug is making it hard for people to find and read it. So I'm looking for other places I can set it up, where it is more likely to get fresh faces who are interested in trying something new. To be clear, I'm not looking to make a buck, this is just a side project I'm doing for free.

Does anyone know free sites with a lot of traffic where I can post my story?

Comment: See also https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/32934/where-can-i-find-resources-about-writing-choose-your-own-adventure-style-books

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I were writing a *Choose Your Own Adventure* story, I'd create a free site on [WordPress](https://wordpress.com/create/) and publish the story there in instalments.

There are hundreds of thousands (if not millions) of writers on that platform and a searchable index of all their posts. The trick with WordPress is that when you reach out to someone, they will reach back to you. Read a story, pop a Like on it, make a Comment or even Follow someone and you will find that that they will do the same for you. It's possible to build up a devoted following within a very short space of time.

It may not be what you imagine you want, but WordPress might be just what you need.

Good luck with your writing.

Comment: I've known a few writers to do well on WordPress hosting, but they usually advertise themselves through Facebook, and if they don't have a lot of interested friends views drop off pretty quick. Do you have any suggestions on how to get visibility if you host this way?

Comment: @called2voyage I went from 0 to 2000 followers in a few months on one WP Blog simply by writing articles daily, liking articles on other WP blogs with similar themes and articles to my own and leaving comments on posts I enjoyed reading. What you give is what you get.

Comment: How do you make a choose your own adventure story on WordPress without buying a premium plan?

Comment: @S.Mitchell - link from page to page in much the same way that a wiki does. Create the alternative storylines like this.

Comment: Isn't that incredibly combersome if you are going to do a story of length and with several choices?

Comment: @S.Mitchell - it works for Wikipedia and I've never found it particularly onerous to use, so maybe it's a question of 'suck it and see' then use it if it suits. :)

Comment: @robertcday I've tried running blogs before, but have had difficulty getting people to pay attention to the content. I've heard that tags are the best way to go, but I'm pretty agnostic to what's popular in that respect. If I do this on Wordpress, what sort of tags should I use? Other people can reply to this too if they have ideas.

Comment: @user102021 - I always use relevant tags. They're useful because they enable people who share your interests to find your posts. If you write a post about (or containing) 'interactive fiction' then use that as a tag. Then, when someone searches WordPress for that phrase, your post will pop up. More useful than this is for you to actively search out other posts containing the tags you use. People who use those tags are telling you that they are interested in that subject, so use that to your advantage by visiting their site & Liking their content. They will then visit you and do the same.

Answer (score 6):

Look for 'interactive fiction' instead of 'choose your own adventure'. There are many sites, some of which even pay for your story or allow you to earn money from it. Look for example at ['Choice of Games'](https://www.choiceofgames.com/about-us/).

Answer (score 0):

## Firstly, please clarify your project's scope.

This first bit may or may not be a relevant recommendation, because I can't tell if you're planning to write out *only* the decisions that some hypothetical group of players/readers make, as you go, or if you wish to create an entire *tree* of decisions and (then?) host it somewhere - but if you are in the former case, I'd try Spacebattles, Sufficient Velocity, or (if you're generally focusing your writing upon prurient matters) Questionable Questing (which is the only one that *fronts* "quests" as their raison d'etre, but it's still a popular keyword I'd use to search for any further examples, and all three sites have dedicated tooling for it).  I've seen websites more focused upon the *latter* case 'in the wild' before, but I have no particular experience with them as a writer or reader.

I believe it may be *possible* to adapt the forum-style hosting of the above-recommended sites to "writing the entire decision tree" cases, but I certainly wouldn't recommend it - at least, not if you're planning to release *all at once.*  I can actually see a "vote on which branch to explore" setup getting some decent traction, though it would still be - odd.

## Secondly, this might be better modeled as a game, than a book, and you should consider pursuing it accordingly.

If I were doing this *myself,* and in the "make the whole thing in one go" case, I'd think about busting out a proper *game engine,* or at least a fancy webpage, *something* more than a bare blog as others have recommended; I don't know if I'd recommend that to someone with no prior experience in programming, but it seems to me that you're approaching the level of complexity in possible results where you'd *need* to start making decisions like "Okay, all these characters give equivalent outcomes in this challenge, modulo some specific bit of character flavor" to actually get your project *done* in a reasonable amount of time/effort.

I've heard of an engine called Twine that is reputed to be good for that, and produces web-hostable output, as far as I understand it. (That is to say, not very far, but hopefully far enough; I've never used it myself, though I know quite a few people who have.)

I will also second that Choice of Games is a decent *reading* experience, though I can't speak to *writing* for it - and, funnily enough, they release their projects as standalone apps.

## TL;DR:

If you're only going to explore one path of the many available routes, look for sites that host "Quests".  They've got the tooling for it.

If you want to do the entire *tree,* this is something that should be developed more like a videogame than a blog.  Choice of Games, if you want to work with a publisher-of-sorts (n.b. I have not looked into them from the authorship side, I have no idea how they work), or the Twine engine, if not, come to me decently well-recommended.  You can *complement* this with a devlog hosted on e.g. Wordpress (or one of the questing sites, for that matter).